# can we prove that is an increasing function

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}\to [0,+\infty)$
wich is continuous, convex, even and
f(t)=0 if and only if t=0

Can we prove that f is increasing

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I know that f' is increasing  that'S all

Comment: @NoraNour Is it strictly convex or just convex? The answer is different for those two conditions.

Comment: So you... "know that f is increasing" and are asking "Can we prove that f is increasing"?!?  Huh?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork $f'$ is the first derivative, not $f$ itself.

Comment: Oh.... quite illegible, when not properly typeset in *MathJax*.  But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If $f(0) = 0$ and $f(\delta_{>0}) > 0$ then what is $f(-\delta)$?  I think it *can't* be increasing.  Or do you mean increasing on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: the function  is even we need it?

Comment: @fleablood i added that f is even it can help

Comment: Well if it is even then it *can't* be increasing! (because $f(-x) = f(x) > 0$ for $-x < 0 < x$.)  What you need to add is the question that you want to know (I presume) is whether it is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ as it clearly can't be increasing on $(-\infty, 0]$ it $f(0) = 0$ is the *maximum* it achieves. ...

Comment: @fleablood  how we prove the increasing on [0,\Infty)?

Comment: Well, you *start* by actually asking the *question* correctly.  As to prove it just use the definition of convex.

Answer (score 4):

Take $$f(x)=x^2$$

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\;\; f''(x)=2\ge 0$$

$$\implies f \text{ is convex at } \Bbb R$$
and
$$f(x)=0 \iff x=0$$

but $ f $ is not increasing.

Comment: $x^2$ is definitely increasing on $[0, +\infty)$

Comment: Right but the question asks for $[0,\infty)$ so that's irrelevant and clearly wrong.

Comment: Ah you're right. My mistake.

Comment: "but the question asks for [0,∞) "  The question *doesn't* ask for that (but maybe it *should*... as that is a very important question.)

Comment: i have that f is even it can help to prove?

Comment: x^2 also it is enen, so under these conditions f is increasing  for $t\geq 0$ ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean increasing on $[0, \infty)$ (it's *decreasing* elsewhere)

The definition of convex is: of any point $s< t$ then line segment connecting $(s,f(s))$ to $(t, f(t))$ will be above the graph.

So as $f(0)=0$ for any $w,t$ so that $0 < w < t$ we must have the $f(w)$ is *below* the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(t, f(t))$.

So $f(t) < $ the $y$ value of the line segment at $x=w$ $< $ then endpoint of the segment as $x = t$ (as the line segment has positive slope) $= f(t)$.

So $0< w< t\implies f(w) < f(t)$.  So $f$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$.

.....

If you wan to be formal:

The equation for the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(t,f(t))$ is

$y_x - 0 = \frac {f(t) -0}{t-0}(x- 0) = \frac {f(t)}t x$.

And because $f$ is concave and $w < t$ we have  $\underbrace{f(w) < y_w}_{\text{because }f\text{ is convex}}=\frac {f(t)}t w=\underbrace{f(t)\cdot \frac tw< f(t)}_{\text{because } w< t\text{ so } \frac wt < 1}$

====

Oh, for pete's sake.....

Look.  Just draw a picture.

Mark off $f(0) = 0$ on the graph.  Then mark off $f(c) = K > 0$ on the graph for some $c > 0$.  Now draw a line for $(0,0)$ to $(c,K)$.  Not it is a line going upward.

That means that all the points of the line segment in that section are less than or equal to $K$ (and only equal to $K$ at the point $(c,K)$.

Now draw the graph of the function between these endpoints, $(0,0)$ and $(c,K)$.  Because we are told the graph is convex, the graph must appear *below* the line.

Now pick a point $x$ on the $x$ axis so that $0\le x < c$.  $f(x) \ge 0=f(0)$ (because the function only maps to $[0,\infty)$.) and $f(x) > 0$ if $x\ne 0$. Now look at the point $(x,y_x)$ on the line segment. Because the function is convex and the graph lies *below* the line we have:

> $0 \le f(x) \le y_x$ with $0 = f(x) = y_0$ *only* when $x = 0$. Otherwise we have $0 < f(x) < y_x$.

But the line is pointing *upward*.  So if $x < c$ we have $y_x < K=f(c)$.

ANd that's that.

If $0 \le x < c$ then $0\le f(x) \le y_x < K =f(c)$ or with the extaneous bits trimmed off:

> If $x \in [0,\infty)$ and $x < c$ then $f(x) < f(c)$.

And *that* is the *definition* of $f$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: I don't understand the proof

Comment: @NoraNour I made it a simple as I could.  What does convex *MEAN* what is the defintion?